# Prove Linear Dependence in $T: V\to W$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Problem:
"Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces and let $T:V \rightarrow W$ be a linear transformation. Prove that, if $\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ is a set of three linearly dependent vectors in $V$, then the set $\{T(v_1), T(v_2), T(v_3)\}$ is also linearly dependent."

First, I would like to note my assumption that $\{T(v_1), T(v_2), T(v_3)\} = \{w_1, w_2, w_3\}$.

If I recall correctly, a set of vectors is linearly dependent if $aV + bW = 0$ and $a = b = 0$. Also, for homogeneous systems if the determinate of the matrix is 0. If this is the case, do I just need to prove that $\det(V) = \det(T(V)) = \det(W) = 0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: A set of vectors $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ is dependent if $\sum \alpha_i v_i = 0$ for some $a_1,a_2,a_3$ not all zero. Use the fact that $T$ is linear to find $b_1,b_2,b_3$ not all zero such that $\sum b_iT(v_i) =0$.

Comment: And this is a viable manner of solving the problem when using a generic solution, correct? Prove that $T(v_1)+T(v_2)+T(v_3) = 0$?

Comment: No, find $b_1,b_2,b_3$ not all zero such that $b_1 T(v_1)+b_2 T(v_2)+b_3 T(v_3) = 0$ (because you want to show that is linearly dependent, if they were linearly independent the former linear combination implies that every $b_i=0$). Another hint: what happens if you put $b_i=a_i$ being $a_i$ the three scalars such that $a_1 v_1+a_2 v_2+ a_3 v_3 = 0$? where the $a_i$ are not all zero (and we know that such $a_i$'s exists because $v_1,v_2,v_3$ is linearly dependent)

Comment: Sorry, that was a really dumb comment. I knew what you meant, I just left out the scalars.